# Vite - change ouput directory of public assets

Tags: javascript, vite

My Spring web app serves all files except the `index.html`, from `/static` directory.

This is my `vite.config.js`

```
export default defineConfig({
  base: "./",
   
  /* ---- */

  build: {
    assetsInlineLimit: 0,
    minify: true,
    rollupOptions: {
      output: {
        assetFileNames: (assetInfo) => {
          var info = assetInfo.name.split(".");
          var extType = info[info.length - 1];
          if (/png|jpe?g|svg|gif|tiff|bmp|ico/i.test(extType)) {
            extType = "img";
          } else if (/woff|woff2/.test(extType)) {
            extType = "css";
          }
          return `static/${extType}/[name]-[hash][extname]`;
        },
        chunkFileNames: "static/js/[name]-[hash].js",
        entryFileNames: "static/js/[name]-[hash].js",
      },
    },
    outDir: "./../backend/src/main/resources/static/articles/",
    emptyOutDir: true,
  },
});
```

As of now, all of the files that are in `/public` are copied to `/` (in the same directory as the /static folder) when build.

[image]

#### I want to copy them to the `/static` folder instead.

Is there any way to do it so?

---